# scipy.optimize + kmeans clustering

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have the following setup for kmeans clustering algorithm that I am implementing for a project:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy
import sys
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import operator
class KMeansClass:
    #takes in an npArray like object
    def __init__(self,dataset,k):
        self.dataset=np.array(dataset)
        #initialize mins to maximum possible value
        self.min_x = sys.maxint
        self.min_y = sys.maxint
        #initialize maxs to minimum possible value
        self.max_x = -(sys.maxint)-1
        self.max_y = -(sys.maxint)-1
        self.k = k

        #a is the coefficient matrix that is continually updated as the centroids of the clusters change respectively.
        # It is an mxk matrix where each row corresponds to a training_instance and each column corresponds to a centroid of a cluster
        #Values are either 0 or 1. A value for a particular training_instance (data_point) is 1 only for that centroid to which the training_instance
        # has the least distance else the value is 0.
        self.a = np.zeros(shape=[self.dataset.shape[0],self.k])
        self.distanceMatrix = np.empty(shape =[self.dataset.shape[0],self.k])


        #initialize mu to zeros of the requisite shape array for now. Change this after implementing max and min methods.
        self.mu = np.empty(shape=[k,2])


        self.findMinMaxdataPoints()
        self.initializeCentroids()
        self.createDistanceMatrix()
        self.scatterPlotOfInitializedPoints()


    #pointa and pointb are npArray like vecors.
    def euclideanDistance(self,pointa,pointb):
        return  np.sqrt(np.sum((pointa - pointb)**2))

    """ Problem Initialization And Visualization Helper methods"""
    ##############################################################################
    #@param: dataset : list of tuples [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...(xm,ym)]
    def findMinMaxdataPoints(self):
        for item in self.dataset:
            self.min_x = min(self.min_x,item[0])
            self.min_y = min(self.min_y,item[1])
            self.max_x = max(self.max_x,item[0])
            self.max_y = max(self.max_y,item[1])



    def initializeCentroids(self):
        for i in range(self.k):
            #each value of mu is a tuple with a random number between (min_x - max_x) and (min_y - max_y)
            self.mu[i] = (random.randint(self.min_x,self.max_x),random.randint(self.min_y,self.max_y))
            self.sortCentroids()   

        print self.mu

    def sortCentroids(self):

        #the following 3 lines of code are to ensure that the mu values are always sorted in ascending order first with respect to the
        #x values and then with respect to the y values.
        half_sorted = sorted(self.mu,key=operator.itemgetter(1))   #sort wrt y values
        full_sorted = sorted(half_sorted,key=operator.itemgetter(0)) #sort the y-sorted array wrt x-values
        self.mu = np.array(full_sorted)

    def scatterPlotOfInitializedPoints(self):
        plt.scatter([item[0] for item in self.dataset],[item[1] for item in self.dataset],color='b')
        plt.scatter([item[0] for item in self.mu],[item[1] for item in self.mu],color='r')
        plt.show()

    ###############################################################################

    #minimizing euclidean distance is the same as minimizing the square of the euclidean distance.
    def calcSquareEuclideanDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(point_a,point_b):
        return np.sum((pointa-pointb)**2)

    def createDistanceMatrix(self):
        for i in range(self.dataset.shape[0]):
            for j in range(self.k):
                self.distanceMatrix[i,j] = calcSquareEuclideanDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(self.dataset[i],self.mu[j])

    def createCoefficientMatrix(self):
        for i in range(self.dataset.shape[0]):
            self.a[i,self.distanceMatrix[i].argmin()] = 1

    #update functions for CoefficientMatrix and Centroid values:
    def updateCoefficientMatrix(self):
        for i in range(self.dataset.shape[0]):
            self.a[i,self.distanceMatrix[i].argmin()]= 1

    def updateCentroids(self):
        for j in range(self.k):
            non_zero_indices = np.nonzero(self.a[:,j])
            avg = 0
            for i in range(len(non_zero_indices[0])):
                avg+=self.a[non_zero_indices[0][i],j]

            self.mu[j] =  avg/len(non_zero_indices[0])

    ############################################################

    def lossFunction(self):
        loss=0;
        for j in range(self.k):
            #vectorized this implementation.
            loss+=np.sum(np.dot(self.a[:,j],self.distanceMatrix[:,j]))
        return loss
```

Here my question pertains to the lossFunction and how to use this with the scipy.optimize package. I would like to minimize the loss function iteratively by performing the following steps:

```
 Repeat until convergence:
      a> Optimize 'a' by keeping mu constant    ( I have an        
         updateCoefficientMatrix method for updating 'a' matrix which is an  
         mXk matrix where we have m training instances and k clusters.)
      b> Optimize 'mu' by keeping 'a' constant (I have an updateCentroids 
         method to do this. where mu is a mXk matrix wherein m is number of 
         training instances and k is the number of clusters and the number of  
         centroids)
```

But I am very new to using scipy.optimize package so I am writing to ask for help as to how to invoke the `scipy.optimize` to achieve my optimization goal as stated above?

Basically I have 2 `m`x`k` matrices and I would like to minimize a `lossFunction()` by first optimizing one `m`x`k` matrix keeping the other constant and in the succeeding step optimize the second matrix keeping the first constant. This can be considered a special case of the expectation maximization problem but unfortunately I haven't quite gotten what the documentation is trying to say so far hence thought I'd turn to SO for help.

Thanks in advance!

And this is part of a class assignment so please do not post code! Any guidance or explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scipy.optimize.minimize` twice with different objective functions.

First run optimization with an objective function that takes `a` as a parameter, and returns the objective value.

As the second step, run `scipy.optimize.minimize` for a second time on a second objective function that takes `mu` as a parameter.

When writing the objective functions, remember that Python has nested functions, which avoids the need for passing `mu` (in the first case) or `a` (in the second case) as additional arguments; although it can be done by `minimize(..., args=[mu])` and `minimize(..., args=[a])`.

Repeat the two-step process in a for loop, until the answer is such that your convergence condition is satisfied.